# Retrieving pure values from acid state queries

Tags: haskell, acid-state

This seems like something that should be easy but how do I get a pure value out of a query if I am using AcidState's Data.Acid.Memory.Pure module. I guess I can generalize the question to "how do I get any value out of the Update monad?". You see, I'm trying to write a test that does the following run-of-the-mill tasks:

- Updates a pure AcidState with an object
- Queries that Object out of the state using IxSet
- Compares the Queried Object and the one returned by the Update for equivalence.

I need a pure "Bool" from this in order to make integration with test frameworks easy. At first I thought I'd simply use runState from Control.Monad.State but I was mistaken (or just didn't do it right). What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using [`Data.Acid.Memory.Pure`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/acid-state/0.8.1/doc/html/Data-Acid-Memory-Pure.html), you can use the [`update`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/acid-state/0.8.1/doc/html/Data-Acid-Memory-Pure.html#v%3aupdate), [`query`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/acid-state/0.8.1/doc/html/Data-Acid-Memory-Pure.html#v%3aquery), and [`update_`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/acid-state/0.8.1/doc/html/Data-Acid-Memory-Pure.html#v%3aupdate_) functions from that module (instead of the ones from [`Data.Acid`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/acid-state/0.8.1/doc/html/Data-Acid.html)) to look at the result of an event purely.  As with regular, impure `acid-state`, you don't simply "run the `Update` and `Query` monads," you have to convert them to an event first.  With `Data.Acid.Memory.Pure`, that means you simply wrap them with the constructors of [`Event`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/acid-state/0.8.1/doc/html/Data-Acid-Memory-Pure.html#t%3aEvent).